# Gradle: How to generate apk just for android and not include the other platforms like iOS,HTML etc

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I am actually making a game using libGDX and I don't want to generate apk for other platforms like html, iOS,Desktop etc.How can I tweak the code to generate apk just for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gradle commad:

```
gradlew android:assembleRelease
```

taken from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-android)